# MySql Inserting From ISNULL Clause

Tags: mysql

After trawling through the web and still not finding any simple answers I'm hoping someone can advise on this.

All I want to do is insert a new row into a table if a value from that table is not null. In this case, I have a table called "Events".

**Events Table**

```
Event_ID | Event_Name | Event_Interval | Event_Date | Event_Interval | Event_Repeat
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          My Event     14               2017-04-04   14               Completion
```

*There are **two** conditions on which I'm working towards; best described using a bit of pseudocode:*

```
IF EVENT_INTERVAL != NULL THEN

     IF EVENT_REPEAT = "DUE" THEN
     DATE_ADD(EVENT_DATE, INTERVAL EVENT_INTERVAL DAY)
     ELSE
     DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL EVENT_INTERVAL DAY)
     END IF

END IF
```

So: when someone completes an event, if the interval value is not null, it inserts a new row to the table where it adds the interval value to either the event date or the current date, depending on the value in "Event_Repeat".

So far I've got to :

```
SELECT
(IF(ISNULL((SELECT e.Event_Interval from events e where e.Event_ID = 1)) = 1, "NULL", "NOT NULL"))
```

This works absolutely fine and can distinguish whether the interval value is NULL or not. I've tried to incorporate/substitute an insert statement into here but as of yet no luck.

If anyone can help to structure this properly (or better!) please feel free as I'm still finding my way around queries etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `IF EVENT_INTERVAL != NULL` never works you can't compare NULL like this you have to use `is not null` instead of `!= NULL`

Comment: I am aware of this thank-you. The code provided in that instance is pseudo-code to describe the process I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

you can create SP as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE update_event
@event_id int
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @event_repeat_temp nvarchar(200)

    SELECT @event_repeat_temp = event_repeat FROM event_table WHERE event_id = @event_id
    PRINT @event_repeat_temp

    IF @event_repeat_temp = 'Due'
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO event_table (event_id , event_name, event_interval, event_date, interval,event_repeat) VALUES (2,'My Event',14,'completion')
    END

    ELSE 

    BEGIN
    //whatever you want
    END
END
```

and call this SP as below

```
EXEC update_event @event_id =1
```